# Postgresql - query an array inside json object

Tags: postgresql

So I have a table with this json column

```
id: 1,    
column: { field: [1, 2, 3] }
```

I want to query all records with field has value of 2 in the array.
I tried `select * from "test-table" where 2=ANY(json_array_elements_text(("column"->>'field')::json));` but it throws a syntax error.

`[0A000] ERROR: set-returning functions are not allowed in WHERE`

My question is how do I construct the query correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the containment operator `@>`:

```
WHERE col::jsonb @> '{ "column": { "field": [2] } }'
```

It would be better to use `jsonb` as data type to begin with.

Comment: thank you. Just wondering if I want the query to return records with either 1 or 2 included in the array, how would I go to do that?

Comment: That would require an `OR`.